# AsyncTask forever loop in Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Currently I use this code for execute a task :

```
AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Void> task = new Task(getApplicationContext(), this.findViewById(android.R.id.content));

task.execute();
```

Now, I would like repeat this task forever in while loop, when the task is finished I would launch a new task..

How can I proceed ?

I know for get the status of task I can use : `task.getStatus();` 
But after ?

Comment: Are you sure you need AsyncTask and not Service ?

Comment: Yes I need AsyncTask because I download a lot of stuff

Comment: if you just want to download stuff, use the DownloadManager...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the details of your codes but here is a recursive solution,

AsyncTask has the `onPostExecute` method. Just call the another Task again in that method. However, if the Task is finished (you control it with whatever flag), start the new activity

```
protected void onPostExecuteTask(Object result) {
    if(!flag){
        //Run the Task again
        }else{
        //Start the new activity
        }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. Though I am leery about a 'forever' task. However it would be easy to use a counter and 'retry' x number of times before quitting. Good solution

Comment: Yep thanks. That's a concept that I use in some places too. For example in httpResponseHandler I put it in onFailure, to retry when the request fails.

Answer (score 2):

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

> The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a
>   second execution is attempted.)

So you can use your AsyncTask instance only one time.

You can of course create another task on your onPostExecute, but it is a bad practice as AsyncTasks are intended to be used to perform short tasks:

> AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds
>   at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of
>   time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by
>   the java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor
>   and FutureTask.